# Setting up a 60 minute timer with pause function

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timer

thanks in advance for any help you can give.

I am trying to set up a 60 minute timer and so far that was the easy part:

```
Dim Breaktime As Date

Sub Timer2Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Breaktimer As TimeSpan = breaktime - DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1)
    Breaklabel.Text = breaktimer.Minutes.ToString("00") & ":" & breaktimer.Seconds.ToString("00")
    If Breaklabel.Text = "00:00" Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        MsgBox("Time Over")
    End If

 End Sub
```

My start button is just a simple start function

```
       Timer2.Start()
button1.Visible = False
button2.Visible = true
```

then I have a stop button that stops the timer and makes the start button visible.

```
           Timer2.STOP()
button2.Visible = False
button1.Visible = true
```

the issue I am having is that the timer is based on Datetime which means when I resume it, it resumes the timer based on the system clock.

What I am trying to do is set up a 60 minute timer in the MM:SS format that is not based on Datetime but for the life of me I cannot get the system to translate 3600 seconds into the MM:SS format and count down the same way as the DateTime does.

Any ideas.

Comment: Maybe look at the TimeSpan and StopWatch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

This is the bones of what you need to do:

```vb
Private countdownStopwatch As New Stopwatch
Private timePeriod As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)

Private Sub StartStop(Optional resetElapsedTime As Boolean = True)
    If countdownStopwatch.IsRunning Then
        'Stop the Stopwatch and the Timer.
        countdownStopwatch.Stop()
        Timer1.Stop()

        If resetElapsedTime Then
            'Reset the elapsed time period.
            countdownStopwatch.Reset()
        End If

        DisplayTimeRemaining()
    Else
        'Start the Stopwatch and the Timer.
        If resetElapsedTime Then
            'Reset the elapsed time period.
            countdownStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        Else
            countdownStopwatch.Start()
        End If

        DisplayTimeRemaining()

        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PauseResume()
    'Start or stop timing without resetting the elapsed time.
    StartStop(False)
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayTimeRemaining()
    Dim timeRemaining = timePeriod - countdownStopwatch.Elapsed

    If timeRemaining < TimeSpan.Zero Then
        timeRemaining = TimeSpan.Zero
    End If

    Label1.Text = timeRemaining.ToString("mm\:ss")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If countdownStopwatch.Elapsed >= timePeriod Then
        StartStop()
    Else
        DisplayTimeRemaining()
    End If
End Sub
```

I'll leave it to you to decide when to enable and disable which `Buttons` and the like.